# Scheduled Newsletters with Products.EasyNewsletter in Plone

Tags: plone, newsletter

How do I set up automated newsletters with EasyNewsletter in Plone?

I know Singing & Dancing has this function however EasyNewsletter has the following features which Singing & Dancing doesn't

- Better breadcrumbs/urls for subscribe links
- More admin control over templates/subscribe/thank you pages etc.
- Doesn't require admin permission

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as EasyNewsletter doesn't provide a mail queue you will have to cheat: I would implement a browser view that checks for "issues" in state draft (maybe using a topic to help the search) and simply trigger the "send" transition. Then, using [Products.cron4plone](http://plone.org/products/cron4plone), you add a cron job that calls that page anytime you prefer.